# Multiple Windows with UNO platform

Tags: uno-platform

I am trying to create application with multiple windows using UNO platform. Does UNO support multiple windows? If so, can someone please point me to webpage showing how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know it is late but it is something. I have something running on Windows OS.

```
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER && WINDOWS && !HAS_UNO
            newWindow = new Window();
#else
            newWindow = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window.Current;
#endif
            //var rootFrame = newWindow.Content as Frame;
            if (newWindow.Content is not Frame rootFrame)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                newWindow.Content = rootFrame;

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MeasurementPage));
            }

            // Ensure the current window is active
            newWindow.Activate();
        }
```

I am still not sure about Linux though.